# Looking for Data Access Layer protection advice

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I'm currently involved in a very large supply chain management software system internal to where I'm employed. The system's UI is currently only implemented through ASP.NET, but we're in development of Windows Forms and Windows Mobile Compact interfaces as well. We have a pretty good setup in terms of separating the interface, business, and data access layers, so we have successfully shared across multiple platforms. However, we have some security concerns for when we distribute our client-based interfaces to the customer.

Several of our data access libraries are distributed with the executable. Simply opening the compiled assembly in Notepad gives full view to any queries within.

For example, let's say we have a class called "User" who implements the method "GetName" as:

> select name from user where id = @id

The problem is that anyone keen enough to open the compiled assembly in Notepad can now see column and table names. Sure, they may not have access to these, but I'd still rather not expose the schema if I don't have to.

The above is just a simple example. Am I going about the thought process incorrectly, or is there a way to protect our queries? (I'd rather not resort to using stored procedures for everything.)

I've thought of forcing out data access layer to be remote and communicating from the business layer via web services so that all database related information is on our internal server that we can protect easier.

Comment: Using Stored Procedures has more benefits than just that.  For one if you change your schema and therefore have to change your SQL queries you won't have to do anything to your C# source code. There are several other benefits to Stored Procs as well.

Comment: It does require that your database and stored procedure language never change.  But I find that it's rare to switch from one database vendor to another.

Comment: Moving your DAL from the client and putting it behind the business layer has a lot of big benefits, it's what's normally called n-tier development. If you need to make a change to your schema it's easy to do if it means updating your servers but very difficult if it means updating every client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the sql from the src, then you are looking at another layer like web services.  While that hides your sql, the services themselves must now be public.  So while those who peek cannot see the db schema, they can still see the data layout.

What the web services allow for is an easier way to make schema changes since now you just have to make sure the data output is always the same.  It also allows for you to move, rename, and/or perform other maintanence with the schema's dbs.  Finally, it would better allow you to pool db connections local instead of over a network and have more processing run at the server.

Comment: This is the approach I was thinking of and requiring some sort of credentials to access the web services.

Comment: the credentials are a given, especially for any services that update the database.  just because your db schema is now hidden does not mean you are free of having valuable information in the exe viewable by notepad.